# How to mongoimport in a remote server (Authentication error)

Tags: mongoimport

With this code I tried to get json data on remote ubuntu server.

```
 mongoimport --port 27017 -d dbtest -c shops --file myfile.json --jsonArray
```

but I only got an error.

```
 Failed: (Unauthorized) command insert requires authentication
```

I tried another codes but I can't authenticate... It only works on localhost.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I solve It!

```
mongoimport -u username -p 'password' --port 27017 -d dbtest -c shops --file myfile.json --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Worked for me with `mongoimport -u username -p 'password' --port 27017 -d dbtest -c shops --file myfile.json --jsonArray`